# does the using statement in entity framework causes performance impact?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, using

How does the using statement in entity framework causes performance impact?

In our project we are using entity framework and perform the db operation as below.

```
`void method()
{
   using(var context= new context())
   {
     //some code....
   }
}`
```

To improve the performance we removed the using statement and initialized the context in constructor and closing the context in finally.

Does this will improve the performance?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: *' we removed the using statement and initialized the context in constructor and closing the context in finally'* can you show how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

Diego Vega (the Senior SDE Lead on Entity Framework) says in [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects?](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html) article, that in common scenarios (if you don't open database connection manually) you don't need to call Dispose on DbContext at all.

Also calling Dispose will not give you significant performance impact, because its very fast comparing to querying database. When you call Dispose on context, connection should be already closed. There is no unmanaged resources to release, so that just fast in-memory operation. Querying database involves network data transmission, executing query on server, reading data from drive on server, creating entities and mapping query results. I would recommend to test your class performance with and without disposing context, and I think you will not notice any difference.